# Django how to merge query results

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) with choices and i'm trying to filter the choices:

```
    PAYMENT_CASH = '0'
    PAYMENT_CARD = '1'
    PAYMENT_BANK = '2'
    PAYMENT_ONLINE = '3'
    PAYMENT = (
        (PAYMENT_CASH, _('Cash')),
        (PAYMENT_CARD, _('Card')),
        (PAYMENT_BANK, _('Bank')),
        (PAYMENT_ONLINE, _('Online')),
    )
options = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT, default='0'), size=4)
```

When i use `Location.objects.filter(city__id='683506').values_list('options', flat=True)` it returns me

```
<QuerySet [['0'], ['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['0', '1', '2'], ['0', '1'], ['0', '1', '2', '3']]>
```

I wish to get all the options that are used.
How can i merge the query or make them into a list and merge them?

This is what i wish to get `['0', '1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
qs = Location.objects.filter(city__id='683506').values_list('options', flat=True)
options = set(chain(*qs))
```

I used set in second line for removing duplicated options.

Comment: Why turn the set back into a list? Seems wasteful.

Comment: In question Nita wrote that he want to get list

Comment: i don't really need a list, just to be merged, let me try it

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce function

```
import functools

query = Location.objects.filter(city__id='683506').values_list('options', flat=True)
oprtions = list(set(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, query)))
```